# Every n-th element of a list in the form of a list

Tags: haskell

I went through a post for this problem but I do not understand it. Could someone please explain it?

Q: Find every n-th element of the list in the form of a list start from the n-th element itself.

```
everyNth :: Int -> [t] -> [t]
everyNth elt = map snd . filter (\(lst,y) -> (mod lst elt) == 0) . zip [1..]
```

Also, please explain how pattern matching can be used for this problem. That is using

```
[]->[]
```

Comment: There's a lot of stuff we could explain here, maybe you'd like to be a bit more precise about what you don't understand? Also, it helps if you start by explaining what you _do_ understand...

Comment: I understand the first line, for the second one, I think it is taking elt, mapping it from tail to head, if the mod result is equal to zero, then it zips particular element to a list.

Comment: Here's a solution with a closely related approach: `nths n= catMaybes.zipWith($)(tail.cycle$Just:replicate(n-1)(const Nothing))`. Feel free to compare and contrast - and then tell us what's missing. If this is a homework assignment, feel free to use it at your own peril. I'll even throw in a golfed version of yet another related approach. Have fun. `\n->concat.zipWith($)(cycle$([2..n]>>[const[]])++[(:[])])`

Comment: More general tip: Try copying your code (without type signature) into your interpreter. Add a `:t` in front of it to get it to tell you the type. Then start removing stuff and see how the type changes. That gives you a rough idea what's what. If some part is harder to understand remove everything around it and keep trying. Interaction with the type checker is your most important tool.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to use pattern matching to 'select every nth element' for particular cases of n:

```
every2nd (first:second:rest) = second : every2nd rest
every2nd _ = []
-- >>> every2nd [1..12]
-- [2,4,6,8,10,12]

every3rd (first:second:third:rest) = third : every3rd rest
every3rd _ = []
-- >>> every3rd [1..13]
-- [3,6,9,12]

every4th (first:second:third:fourth:rest) = fourth : every4th rest
every4th _ = []
-- >>> every4th [1..12]
-- [4,8,12]
```

For the general case, though, we're out of luck, at least with that particular approach. Patterns like those above will need some definite length to be definite patterns. The composed function you mention starts from the thought that we do know how to find every nth member of `[1..]`, namely if it's a multiple of n

```
multiple n m = m `mod` n == 0
-- >>> filter (multiple 3) [1..12]
-- [3,6,9,12]
```

So the solution you are trying to understand zips `[1..]` with the list

```
index xs = zip [1..] xs
-- >>> index [1..5]
-- [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)]
-- >>> index "hello"
-- [(1,'h'),(2,'e'),(3,'l'),(4,'l'),(5,'o')]
```

Then it filters out just those pairs whose first element is a multiple of n

```
every_nth_with_index n xs = filter (\(m,a) -> multiple n m) (index xs)
-- >>> every_nth_with_index 3 [1..12]
-- [(3,3),(6,6),(9,9),(12,12)]
-- >>> every_nth_with_index 3 "stackoverflow.com"
-- [(3,'a'),(6,'o'),(9,'r'),(12,'o'),(15,'c')]
```

Then it gets rid of the ancillary construction, leaving us with just the second element of each pair:

```
every_nth n xs = map snd (every_nth_with_index n xs)
-- >>> every_nth 3 [1..12]
-- [3,6,9,12]
-- >>> every_nth 3 "stackoverflow.com"
-- "aoroc"
```

Retracinging our steps we see that this is the same as

```
everyNth elt = map snd . filter (\(lst,y) -> (mod lst elt) == 0) . zip [1..]
```

Answer (score 3):

With a little cheating, you can define `everyNth` using pattern matching. Really, we're abstracting out the part that makes pattern matching difficult, as pointed out in Michael's answer.

```
everyNth n lst = e (shorten lst)
                 where shorten = drop (n-1) -- here's the cheat
                       e [] = []
                       e (first:rest) = first : e (shorten rest)
```

Comment: As a bonus, this way is efficient!

Comment: One gripe: pattern matching never fails here. See my answer.

Comment: This improves the combinator approach to be similarly efficient, at least in the composition I checked ... `everyNth n = map snd . filter fst . zip (circ n) where circ n = drop  1 $ cycle (True : replicate (n-1) False)`

Comment: @Michael, that's a nice use of fusion! Unfortunately, I suspect you'll start to run into a bit of trouble once `n` gets large enough that the cycle size is comparable to the CPU cache size.

Comment: @dfeuer oh I see, yes ... I was testing with `n=2`. At say  `n = 2000000` mine takes almost three times as much time.

Answer (score 3):

The notorious fold fan strikes again.

```
everyNth n xs = foldr go (`seq` []) xs n where
  go x r 0 = x : r (n - 1)
  go _ r k = r (k - 1)
```

This is very similar to [chepner's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39040160/1477667) but it integrates the dropping into the recursion. Rewritten without the fold, it's pure pattern matching:

```
everyNth n = go n where
  go k [] = k `seq` []
  go 0 (x : xs) = x : go (n - 1) xs
  go k (_ : xs) = go (k - 1) xs
```

Comment: Is the first match equivalent to `go !k [] = []`?

Comment: Off topic (there's no pattern matching) I think the following reads quite nicely `everyNth n = map head . takeWhile (not . null) . iterate (drop n)`

Comment: @Cirdec, I don't much care for unnecessary partial functions, and I am a fan of list fusion. I don't know if there's a particularly pretty way to get the fusion. You could limit yourself to total functions if we had `takeWhileJust :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]` with `takeWhileJust f (x : xs) | Just y <- f x = y : takeWhileJust f xs; takeWhileJust _ _ = []`.

Comment: @chepner, yes. I just didn't want to bother with extensions for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have never seen Haskell before then this takes a bit of explaining.

```
everyNth :: Int -> [t] -> [t]
everyNth elt = map snd . filter (\(lst,y) -> (mod lst elt) == 0) . zip [1..]
```

First, note that the type has two arguments, but the definition has only one. This is because the value returned by `everyNth` is in fact another function. `elt` is the Int, and the expression in the second line creates a new function that does the job.

Second, note the "." operators. This is an operator that joins two functions together. It is defined like this:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

Here is an equivalent version of the definition with the second argument made explicit:

```
everyNth elt xs = map snd (filter (\(lst y) -> (mod lst elt) == 0) (zip xs))
```

When you see a bunch of functions in a chain linked by "." operators you need to read it from right to left. In my second version pay attention to the bracket nesting. `zip [1..] xs` is the inner-most expression, so it gets evaluated first. It turns a list like `["foo", "bar"]` into `[(1, "foo"),(2, "bar")]`. Then this is filtered to find entries where the number is a multiple of `elt`. Finally the `map snd` strips the numbers back out to return just the required entries.